# Get value of an attribute in C#

Tags: c#, json, object

I have a class which looks like this:

```cs
    public class currentlyplaying
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The values are set by deserializing a json object. Now i want to acces the name of the Item. I thought i could do that like this:

```cs
    instance.Item.name;
```

But i can't access any of the classes, let alone the attributes of the object.

Comment: You probably don't want a nested class. Read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: `class currentlyplaying` does not have a property called `Item`. It could have if you declared `public Item Item {get; set;}` in it.

Comment: You may mistake the terms attribute and Property. `name` is a Property of the `Item` class. Your instance also does not expose a property of `Item` type. Nested classes are not automatically a property of the enclosiing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance of Item class inside of **currentlyplaying** class.

```
    public class currentlyplaying
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
        public Item item;
    }
```

Then you can easily use it like
`instance.item.name;`

In my opinion, though, the definition of Item class should not be inside of currentlyplaying class.